# I want to insert same set of data into different related tables

Tags: sql

im using oracle database and need help to get a script cause it takes to do it manually. please help

Comment: Lets first start by adding your code in. Then you can inform us of what you have already tried and what errors came from trying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to insert the data from one source to multiple tables...

```
INSERT ALL
INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) values (source_table.col1, source_table.col2, source_table.col3)
INTO table2 (col1, col2, col4) values (source_table.col1, source_table.col2, source_table.col4)
INTO table3(col1, col5, col6) values (source_table.col1, source_table.col5, source_table.col6) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\excel-sql-server.xls', [Sheet1$])
```

Comment: okay, that i can do but the problem is that the data is not on any table. It's data provided as a document and need to insert in existing table with similar records. I have four tables and have to insert the same information. Thanks